# How do I get the Return Stmt of objective-c through clang-3.9?

Tags: objective-c, macos, clang, llvm, static-analysis

I am a rookie in doing the static-analysis of objective-c through clang now.
I face a problem that when I find the ReturnStmt through RecursiveASTVisitor ,clang sometimes can not find the ReturnStmt.
The RecursiveASTVisitor code like this:

```
    class MyASTVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<MyASTVisitor> {
public:
    MyASTVisitor(Rewriter &R) : TheRewriter(R) {}
    .........
        else if(isa<ReturnStmt>(s)){
            //The Return Stmt find block
            ReturnStmt *returnStat = cast<ReturnStmt>(s);
            TheRewriter.InsertText(returnStat->getLocStart(),"//the return stmt\n",true,true); 
        }
        return true;
    }}
```

And that's the result 
The first result can find the return stmt

```
int main (int argc, const char* argv[])  {  
@autoreleasepool {  
    //the func--->NSLog() begin called!
    NSLog (@"Programming is fun!");  
}  
//the return stmt
return 0; }
```

But the second can not find it

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}}
```

Comment: Well I didn't get your tag: [how to mention tag any user in a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97471/how-to-mention-tag-any-user-in-a-post). I case you want to tag someone. As for the question, I can see why that would happen, I will compile an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain how clang AST works with a small example. Assume this code exists in temp.cpp

```
int b()
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return b();
}
```

Now let's see what is the clang's AST representation of the above code is: (By the way, this is something you can do anytime you don't see your code doing what it should. Look at the raw AST to see what is wrong. To get the raw AST dump from clang we will run this.

```
clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only temp.cpp
```

This gives us this output:

```
|-FunctionDecl 0x5f952e0 <t.cpp:2:1, line:5:1> line:2:5 used b 'int (void)'
| `-CompoundStmt 0x5f95400 <line:3:1, line:5:1>
|   `-ReturnStmt 0x5f953e8 <line:4:2, col:9>
|     `-IntegerLiteral 0x5f953c8 <col:9> 'int' 0
`-FunctionDecl 0x5f95440 <line:7:1, line:10:1> line:7:5 main 'int (void)'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x5f95620 <line:8:1, line:10:1>
    `-ReturnStmt 0x5f95608 <line:9:2, col:11>
      `-CallExpr 0x5f955e0 <col:9, col:11> 'int'
        `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x5f955c8 <col:9> 'int (*)(void)' <FunctionToPointerDecay>
          `-DeclRefExpr 0x5f95570 <col:9> 'int (void)' lvalue Function 0x5f952e0 'b' 'int (void)'
```

If you look at the first FunctionDecl for function b, it's a simple return statement which returns the integer value 0. But, now if you look at the FunctionDecl for main, you can see that returnStmt calls CallExpr which then gets the return from function b. This is exactly what is happening in your case. One return statement is getting detected and one is not.

What you can do in this case is call [getRetValue()](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ReturnStmt.html) of `ReturnStmt` which will give you an `Expr` type and you need to resolve that for different possible return cases.

Comment: I hava make another way to log the return statement of function ,and this method can use in .m and .mm file.Like this #define return if(log(XXX),1) return